# How do i update a record in mysql table row

Tags: mysql

I am stuck with following statement. i dont know where the problem is. can someone please look into it and let me know, is it correct or not and if not than whats the correct one to update the row.

```
SELECT id FROM records WHERE user_id = 12119 AND field_id = 9
UPDATE records (user_id, field_id, value) VALUES (12119, 9, 'dallas')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to update `value` column for user with id 12119.

```
UPDATE records 
SET value ='dallas'
WHERE user_id = 12119 
  AND field_id = 9;
```

Answer (score 0):

use mysql update query like this

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1=value, column2=value2
WHERE some_column=some_value
```